# aside can't be floated in Safari

Tags: html, safari

i got the following problem. 
I try to float a aside object to the right, but it just doesn't work out in safari. The strange thing about it is that my code works if I replace the aside with a div tag. Do u know how to solve this prom?

```
.container > *{
 display:inline-block;
}
.content{ float:left;}
.content2{ float:right;}


<div class="container">
    <div class="content">Content</div>
    <aside class="content2">Aside</aside>
</div>
```

Greetz

Answer (score 0):

It's because you've closed your aside tag with a div tag. You need to close it with an aside tag like so:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="content">Content</div>
    <aside class="content2">Aside</aside>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the correction, but that's not the problem. i just mistyped it here on stack overflow.

Comment: Can you provide a link to the issue?

Comment: Sadly I can't as it's running on a local machine only.